# Inconsistent margin for footer (Word 2007)

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

Margins between text and footers in different page of the document is inconsistent. Margins also change while editing the footer.

page 11:

[image]

page 11 with footer selected:

[image]

page 12:

[image]

page 12 with footer selected:

[image]